# UIBlurEffect is always nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uivisualeffectview

I've been trying to add a blur effect to my app and upon debugging it using breakpoints, the UIBlurEffect variable is always nil.

Following is the code I am using:

```
UIBlurEffect *effect = [[UIBlurEffect alloc] init];
effect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
UIVisualEffectView *bluredView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect: effect];
bluredView.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:bluredView];
```

I have tried a couple different things, for example instead of alloc and init UIBlurEffect, directly using it as follows:

```
UIBlurEffect *effect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
```

It is still always set to nil.
Is there an import I'm missing? I have imported UIKit in my .h file but 'effect' is always nil for some reason.

If anyone has experience the same, I would really appreciate it if you could share your experience.

Any help on the matter would be great!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you assume it is nil, because you cannot see it or how do you detect it?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should've mentioned this more clearly. I set the breakpoint at the line: [self.view addSubview:bluredView]; and saw that bluredView was nil. So I set a breakpoint at: UIVisualEffectView *bluredView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect: effect]; and saw that effect was nil

Comment: Set the breakpoint at a line under the actual line. The break point stops the code before running the line it's on which means that the `UIVisualEffectView *bluredView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect: effect];` isn't declared when you test the value. Set the breakpoint below and hold your mouse over the line you want to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running on iOS 7?  UIBlurEffect is only available on iOS 8 and above.

Comment: Thank you so much for you response. It indeed was the version issue.

Answer (score 0):

These two Gits may help you, even I firstly didn't see they use UIBlurImage. Try them :)

[LBBlurredImage](http://github.com/lukabernardi/LBBlurredImage)

[BTGlassScrollView](http://github.com/BTLibrary/BTGlassScrollView)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will check the Gits out. In my current case, as @EwamMellor pointed out, the devices it was showing nil on is running iOS.